# VHDL: How to declare a variable width generic

Tags: vhdl

I want to create a VHDL entity with a one generic that changes the width of another generic.

```
entity lfsr_n is 
generic (
    WIDTH           : integer := 32; -- counter width
    POLYNOMIAL      : std_logic_vector (WIDTH-1 downto 0) := "1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_0010"
);
```

Unfortunately, it seems I can't reference an earlier defined generic later in the generic list. Active-HDL gives the following errors:

Error: COMP96_0300: modules/m3_test_load/lfsr_n.vhd : (26, 45): Cannot reference "WIDTH" until the interface list is complete.

Error: COMP96_0077: modules/m3_test_load/lfsr_n.vhd : (26, 66): Undefined type of expression. Expected type 'STD_LOGIC_VECTOR'.

One workaround would be to make POLYNOMIAL a port. But it properly should be a generic since since the value is constant at elaboration time. I know that if I apply a constant to the port, it will synthesize the way I want and optimize the constants values into the module, but I'd like to find someway to make it a generic. Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the `POLYNOMIAL` parameter to remain a generic you can specify it as an unconstrained array. You can also dispense with the `WIDTH` parameter by replacing all references by `POLYNOMIAL'range`, `POLYNOMIAL'length-1 downto 0`, or `POLYNOMIAL'length` as needed.

```vhdl
entity lfsr_n is
  generic (
    POLYNOMIAL : std_logic_vector := X"FFAA55BB"
  );
  port (
    -- Vector with copied range (defaults to ascending from 0)
    state  : out std_logic_vector(POLYNOMIAL'range);

    -- Vector with forced descending range
    state2 : out std_logic_vector(POLYNOMIAL'length-1 downto 0)
  );
end entity;
```

Unconstrained arrays are a powerful feature that help simplify code by implicitly controlling widths rather than needing a dedicated generic parameter. When used effectively they reduce the number of hard-coded array sizes in your source resulting in naturally resizable logic. You can freely change the `POLYNOMIAL` generic to another value with a different length and the rest of your logic should adapt without any additional effort.

Answer (score 0):

There's an entity declarative part following any generic and any port declaration:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity lfsr_n is 
    generic (
        WIDTH: integer := 32 -- counter width
    );
    port (
        foo:    integer
    );
    constant POLYNOMIAL: std_logic_vector (WIDTH-1 downto 0) 
            := B"1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_0010";
end entity;
architecture foo of lfsr_n is
begin
end architecture;
```

This analyzes and elaborates showing the generic is properly used.

You could also note that the literal you assign to the std_logic_vector doesn't adapt to changing WIDTH. I would have thought these '1's stand for tap off locations and you'd expect these could change from one LFSR length to another.

You could convey the 'WIDTH' in the polynomial constant:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity lfsr_n is 
    generic (
        -- WIDTH: integer := 32; -- counter width
        POLYNOMIAL: std_logic_vector := 
                 B"1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_0010"
    );
    port (
        foo:    integer
    );
    -- constant POLYNOMIAL: std_logic_vector (WIDTH-1 downto 0)
    --         := B"1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_0010";
end entity;
architecture foo of lfsr_n is
    signal shft_register:  std_logic_vector (0 to POLYNOMIAL'LENGTH-1);
begin
end architecture;
```

Or:

```
architecture foo of lfsr_n is
    -- signal shft_register:  std_logic_vector (0 to POLYNOMIAL'LENGTH-1);
    -- or
    signal shift_register: std_logic_vector(POLYNOMIAL'RANGE);
```