# Bit order for generaic std_logic_vector with dynamic width

Tags: generics, vhdl

I have a generic `std_logic_vector` with dynamic length as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28513417/12978575

```
entity lfsr is
    generic(
        INIT : std_logic_vector
    );
[...]
end entity;
```

Later, I want to access the bits of `INIT` individually in a way where order matters. How can I ensure that the bit order of `INIT` will always be a `downto` bit order (for example `3 downto 0` when having 4 bit length) and never a `to` order (for example `0 to 3`)?

Comment: With VHDL 2008, generics can read other generics. So you can have a first generic to set the length: `generic( INIT_LEN : natural; INIT : std_logic_vector(INIT_LEN-1 downto 0);` This way you guarantee that the `INIT` generic is always `downto`

Comment: There is no dynamic width in VHDL other than access type allocated array objects. Objects cannot otherwise be unconstrained after elaboration. Dynamically elaborated subprograms have statements (procedures) or calls (functions) that provide constrained parameters. Here INIT has a subtype provided by association in a generic map where an actual must be provided and supplies the subtype during elaboration. It's globally constant (defined at elaboration, here a generic constant), not dynamic (the value of a variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a deterministic descending range with an object alias:

```vhdl
library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity lfsr is
    generic (
        INIT:  std_logic_vector
    );
    -- In the entity declarative part:
    alias DINIT: std_logic_vector(INIT'LENGTH - 1 downto 0)  is INIT; 
end entity lfsr;
```

Use DINIT in the architecture where you'd have previously used INIT.

You could alias INIT in the architecture block declarative part or any declarative region (e.g. process statement, block statement, generic_statement, subprogram definition) in the architecture within the scope of the generic declaration:

```vhdl
library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity lfsr is
    generic (
        INIT:  std_logic_vector
    );
end entity lfsr;

architecture foo of lfsr is
    alias DINIT: std_logic_vector(INIT'LENGTH - 1 downto 0)  is INIT;
begin
end architecture;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your vector will later be connected to an outside block, you can't ensure anything. You just have to care about it when you'll connect it.

Comment: If ensuring the order isn't possible, is there a way to index the least significant bit - independent of the order?

Comment: To be clear, the nature of what you are manipulating is wires and only wires. There i no such concept as MSB or LSB when you talk about wires. The way to access a given wire in a wire vector (a logic vector) is `my_vector(x)` where `x` is the index of the wire in the vector. For example to ensure `my_vector(0)` give the LSB of a given number you have to ensure that it is indeed the LSB of the number that is connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ASSERT INIT'left >= INIT'right REPORT "INIT Bit Order Error" SEVERITY FAILURE;
```

If your testbench elaborates successfully, you know the order is correct.